# Java Regular expression with multi variable and arrayList of string

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, user-controls

I created this Java method:

```
public String isInTheList(List<String> listOfStrings)
{
    /*
     * Iterates through the list, and if the list contains the input of the user,
     * it will be returned.      
     */
    for(String string : listOfStrings)
    {
        if(this.answer.matches("(?i).*" + string + ".*"))
        {
            return string;
        }
    }    
    return null;     
}
```

I use this method in a `while` block in order to validate user input. I want to check if that input matches the concatenation of two different predefined `ArrayList`s of `String`s.

The format of the input must be like this:

```
  (elementOfThefirstList + " " + elementOfTheSecondList)
```

where the `String`s `elementOfThefirstList` and `elementOfTheSecondList` are both elements from their respective list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstListOfString.size(); i++)
{
     if(userInput.contains(firstListOfString.get(i) + " " + userInput.isInTheList(secondListOfString)))
     {  
         isValid = true;//condition for exit from the while block
     }
}
```

It work if the user input is like this:

> elementOfThefirstList + " " + elementOfTheSecondList

However, it will also work if the user input is like this:

> elementOfThefirstList + " " + elementOfTheSecondList + " " + anotherElementOfTheFirstList

How can I modify my regular expression, as well as my method, in order to have exactly one repetition of elements in both lists concatenated with a space between them?

I tried with another regular expression and I think that I will use this: "{1}". However, I am not able to do that with a variable.

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to do that with a variable? Can you specify how you are getting other strings concatenated onto that string?

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provide as to how you are getting this issue, there is little that can be said about how to fix it. I strongly encourage you to look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) quantifiers tutorial before moving forward.

Let's look at some solutions.

1. For example, lets look at the line:
   `if(this.answer.matches("(?i).*" + string + ".*"))`
   What you are trying to do is to see if `this.answer` contains `string`, ignoring case (I doubt you need the last .*). But you are using a **Greedy Quantifier** to compare them. If the issue is arising due to an input error in this comparison, I would consider looking at the linked tutorial for **Reluctant Quantifiers**.
2. Okay, so it wasn't a quantifier issue. The other possible fix may be this block of code:
   `for(int i = 0; i < firstListOfString.size(); i++)
   {
        if(userInput.contains(firstListOfString.get(i) + " " + userInput.isInTheList(secondListOfString)))
        {  
            isValid = true;//condition for exit from the while block
        }
   }`
   I don't know you you got `userInput` to have the `contains`method, but I assume that you used containment to call the `String` method. If this is the case, there could be a solution to the issue. You would only have to state that it is valid if and only if it is **equal to** an element from the first list and a matching element from the second string.
3. The final solution I have for you is simple. **If there are no other spaces present within the list elements**, you could `split` the concatenated `String` on a space and check how many elements the resulting array contains. If it is greater than two, then you have an invalid concatenation.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thank for your answer! 
i solved my problem with double for (like a matrix) and this condition userInput.matches(firstListOfString().get(i)+"{1} "+secondListOfString().get(j)+"{1}"))